# Which bluetooth "Device Class" is the PS4 dual-shock controller?

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, ps4

I am planning to build a quadcopter that includes using a RaspberryPi 3. I would like to control it using my PS4 controller through a bluetooth connection. I was wondering what the maximum range would be between the controller and RPi. I notice that there is a `Device Class` to define different bluetooth devices:

https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+the+maximum+distance+for+bluetooth+connection&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS709US709&oq=what+is+the+maximum+distance+for+bluetooth+connection&aqs=chrome..69i57.41565j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I searched the docs as well but they weren't very helpful. http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/bluetooth.html

Comment: I have a hunch the PS4 controller is at most a `Class 2`. I might have to buy a dji or parrot controller that has larger bluetooth `Transmit Power` to control it at longer ranges. Will need to research if this is the case.